# Biblatex: No author year delimiter for one literature type

Tags: biblatex, delimiters

I am using biblatex/biber and have - among books and articles for which i use several bibliographies - the document type "misc", which I use for legal documents.

I am trying to implement a specific citing style for these documents, which roughly follows the following logic: "*Court* v. *dd.mm.year*, *...decision name and number*".

Since I want to keep it simple and always \fullcite these cases, my idea was to simply add the "v. dd.mm." to the author by hand and only include the year in the year field. This way biblatex can sort the judgements by year without much further need to redefine the misc-type, apart for removing the parenthesis around the "year" and removing the space between the author and the year.

I have trouble implementing this last single point of my idea, as can be seen in the following picture - there is space between the "author v. dd.mm." and "year", which I would like to remove.

[image]

I tried my best to resolve this problem, but get an nameyeardelim undefined error. Any ideas how to solve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote, maxcitenames=3, language=german, style=authoryear-ibid, backend=biber, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{lit.bib}

\renewcommand*{\ifentrytype{misc}{\nameyeardelim}{}}


\begin{document}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{parens}{#1\addcomma}
Test\autocite{eugh29807}

\printbibliography[title={Europ\"aischen Union Rechtsakte}, type=misc]
\end{document}
```

My lit.bib:

```
@misc{eugh29807,
    Author = {{EuG~v.~15.6.}},
    Date-Added = {2016-06-13 14:46:17 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-06-13 14:46:45 +0000},
    Howpublished = {Rs. T-298/07, T-312/97, Slg. 2000, II-2325 -- Alzetta},
    Year = {2000}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biblatex 3.4 introduces new commands to define "delimiters" and these are context dependent.

The format of a delimiter is defined by the command

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[context]{delimiter}{code}
```

The context can be used to indicate where the delimiter is used (bibliography, citation, in text citation and so on, and it is possible to defined new contexts).

For the specific case so we can use

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\ifentrytype{misc}{}{\addspace}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\ifentrytype{misc}{}{\addspace}}
```

The first definition is to change the appearance in citation, the second one use  the `bib` option. The `bib` option is used for the environment created by `\printbibliography` and when a bib driver is used.

With the addition above the MWE (with an additional bib entry to illustrate the difference) produces

[image]

Comment: So I tried to modify your general example according to what I need it to look like, as described in my original post and, accordingly, red the "renewcommand"-command. Since I have several bibliographies, the context needs to be the misc type and no delimiter between author and year: "\DeclareDelimFormat[misc]{nameyeardelim}{}". This does not work, I get an "undefined control sequence" error.

Comment: yes. I get "undefined control  sequence" errors for all of these. But I am also not sure as to how to exactly implement your suggestions.

Comment: So, it seems you have a version of bib latex older than 3.4. You might consider to update

Comment: Woohoo, you are right! It works now. Update my MacTex Version and it seems to work.